# Android Lunar Lander Double Synchronizes

Tags: android, thread-safety

I'm poring over some of the `LunarView` code for the Java Lunar Lander sample (API-8 version). I noticed this oddity:

```
public synchronized void restoreState(Bundle savedState) {
            synchronized (mSurfaceHolder) {
                        // ...
            }
}
```

Why double-synchronization? Doesn't the first synchronize already guarantee only a single thread can enter this method at one time?

Comment: This type of nested locking is deadlock prone...

Answer (score 0):

No.

The internal synchronized block is locking onto the mSurfaceHolder object whilst the use of the synchronized keyword on the method is locking onto the class instance itself.

the synchronized keyword is basically like using a lock on the instance object..

```
public synchronized void doSomething()
{
    // Do some stuff
}
```

Is exactly the same as...

```
public void doSomething()
{
    synchronized (this)
    {
        // Do some stuff
    }
}
```

Locking onto an object means that if a piece of synchronized code is executing with a lock on a particular object, then any other synchronised piece of code (that uses the same object for the lock) will have to wait until the first one finishes.

Comment: So you're saying the first block synchronizes within the `this` class, and the second block synchronizes with anything that locks `mSurfaceHolder`? Why would they do that?

Comment: Yes that is correct. The code basically means that if there is a lock on either the class instance (this) OR the mSurfaceHolder object, then the executing code has to wait until that thread gives up the lock.

Comment: Okay, so the burning question is still *why?* What are they accomplishing? Is it because something else shouldn't be accessing `mSurfaceHolder` at the same time, from a different method?

Comment: Yes that's correct again. But without looking at the full code I can't explain why that would be.. Look at the code inside the block and try and determine why they would need to protect against this concurrent access. You will eventually find the answer :-)